# How to show Ribbon in listviewbyquery webpart?

Tags: list-view, ribbon

I created a custom page in SharePoint that uses standard master page. On the page I am using a listviewbyquery control, but i cannot find how to enable ribbon options for the list.

How do I enable the ribbon?

Comment: same problem here. I have a custom action binded on a content type on a list that I show in a custom web part via ListViewByQuery webpart, and I'm not able to show the list ribbon. So I can't execute my custom action. Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
setTimeout(function() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2");
    if(elem != null) {
        var dummyevent = new Array();
        dummyevent["target"] = elem;
        dummyevent["srcElement"] = elem;
        WpClick(dummyevent);
    }
}, 2000);
</script>
```